# how to detect Browser with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

i want detect diffrent borwsers and version with javascript or jquery but i dont getting anything on it.

I need the code to recognize the user browser and redirect to download the addon.

detect all browers like

- crome
- mozilla
- safari
- ie7,ie8,ie9
- opera

please help me.

Comment: Have you even tried to find the information yourself? There is ample amounts of resources and information regarding this

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_nav_all

Comment: Press F12, go to console, type `navigator.userAgent`, profit

Comment: search result will give link of external js which i don't want i need to simple function of it. i do not want to add external js @RoryPicko92

Comment: @jigneshkheni external js? js is js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="example"></div>

<script>

txt = "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Language: " + navigator.language + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Online: " + navigator.onLine + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>User-agent language: " + navigator.systemLanguage + "</p>";

document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=txt;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**[Refer This to Know More](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Check this site: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html. It contains a JS function which detects you browser and version.

Answer (score 0):

[browserdetect.js](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)

Use the above link to download browserdetect.js to detect browser. You just need to call and function and it will return the browser for you and it's version too.

Answer (score 0):

```
var agent = navigator.userAgent;
var browsers = ['Chrome', 'Firefox', 'MSIE 6', 'MSIE 7', 'MSIE 8', 'MSIE 9', 'MSIE 10'];
for (i=0;i<browsers.length;i++){
    if(agent.indexOf(browsers[i]) != -1){
        alert(browsers[i]);
    }
}
```